# Move layout when edittext show keyboard in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment with a `EditText` and when I show the keyboard for write the `EditText` doesn't show completely.

I have this in the fragment but doesnt work:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: try adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"` in your manifest..

Comment: is your activity a fullscreen activity???

Comment: No, its a normal activity.

Comment: try just adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

Comment: Yes, it works.
Where can i find information about this parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

and you can see more about the parameters **[here](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html)**

Comment: In a fragment ? haha how you can put a fragment in the manifest ?

Answer (score -2):

You can Use a [scrollview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) it scrolls up so the screen